# jQuery animate(), expand a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

HTML:

```
<div id="box0"><img src="http://s14.postimg.org/9x1nrefy5/A_Sunday_on_La_Grande_Jatte.png" id="pic0"></div>
<div id="box1"><img src="http://s14.postimg.org/hbqzjs1tp/starry_night.png" id="pic1"></div>
<div id="box2"><img src=http://s14.postimg.org/x7ftn2se5/mona_lisa.png" id="pic2"></div>
<div id="box3"><img src="http://s14.postimg.org/k4k73t265/the_scream.png" id="pic3"></div>
```

CSS:

```
        * {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            z-index: 0;
        }
        img {
            position: relative;
        }
        div {
            position: absolute;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 8px solid #61260D;
        }
        #box0 {     /* A Sunday on La Grande Jatte */
            height: 150px;
            width: 120px;
            top: 300px;
            left: 100px;
        }
        #pic0 {
            left: -15px;
            top: -15px;
            height: 337px;
            width: 500px;
        }
        #box1 {     /* Starry Night */
            height: 100px;
            width: 400px;
            top: 150px;
            left: 100px;
        }
        #pic1 {
            left: -35px;
            top: -20px;
            height: 300px;
            width: 480px;
        }
        #box2 {     /* Mona Lisa */
            height: 150px;
            width: 100px;
            top: 190px;
            left: 50px;
        }
        #pic2 {
            left: -20px;
            top: -20px;
            height: 300px;
            width: 198px;
        }
        #box3 {     /* The Scream */
            height: 200px;
            width: 160px;
            top: 60px;
            left: 200px;
        }
        #pic3 {
            left: -30px;
            top: -20px;
            height: 400px;
            width: 314px;
        }
```

Javascript:

```
        var h = [];
        var w = [];
        var left = [];
        var top = [];
        var speed = 300;

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
            h[i] = $('#box'+i).css('height');
            w[i] = $('#box'+i).css('width');
            left[i] = $('#pic'+i).css('left');
            top[i] = $('#pic'+i).css('top');

        }
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
            $('div').hover(
                function() {
                    $(this).stop().css({'zIndex':'5'}).animate({
                        height : $(this).children().css('height'),
                        width : $(this).children().css('width')
                    }, speed);
                    $(this).children().animate({
                        left : '0',
                        top : '0'
                    }, speed);
                },
                function() {
                    $(this).stop().css({'zIndex':'0'}).animate({
                        height : h[i],
                        width : w[i]
                    }, speed);
                    $(this).children().animate({
                        left : left[i],
                        top : top[i]
                    }, speed);
                }
            );
        }
```

What I want to do is when the cursor enter a div, the div will expand to the image size and the image embedded will change its location using animate().
It does expand well, however, the div does not restore its original size when the cursor leaves.
[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hanglout/dVz6H/7/)

Comment: another problem: i can't use $('#pic'+i) and so i used $(this).children(). so why can't i use that? is it a bug??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Made a working fiddle for you: 
http://jsfiddle.net/U4nRq/1/

**EDIT:**
To fix it so the return size is constant:

```
    var speed = 300;

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
        $("#box" + i).attr("stored_h",  $("#box" + i).css('height'));
        $("#box" + i).attr("stored_w",  $("#box" + i).css('width'));
        $("#box" + i).attr("stored_left",  $("#box" + i).children().css('left'));
        $("#box" + i).attr("stor_top",  $("#box" + i).children().css('top'));
    }

$('div').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop().css({'zIndex':'5'}).animate({
            height : $(this).children().css('height'),
            width : $(this).children().css('width')
        }, speed);
        $(this).children().animate({
            left : '0',
            top : '0'
        }, speed);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop().css({'zIndex':'0'}).animate({
            height : $(this).attr("stored_h"),
            width : $(this).attr("stored_w")
        }, speed);
        $(this).children().animate({
            left : $(this).attr("stored_left"),
            top : $(this).attr("stored_top")
        }, speed);
    }
);
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/U4nRq/9/

Comment: Good answer, but you're missing a " in your second box (like the OP) and you also deleted one of the images...

Comment: Thang: You can use an array, but you really don't need to in this case. Since you are putting the hover event on all divs. If you don't want that, you can still use a class. If you want to use an array, you have to put the event on the div ids(but it would look ugly to read).

Comment: Zeaklous: Thank you. My sloppieness haunts me >.<

Comment: Naoe: Thanks, but is it a bug that sometimes the div cannot restore its original size after the cursor leaves?  [Original](http://postimg.org/image/8yhy53xjx/) and [Bug?](http://postimg.org/image/hnj6qotdj/)

Comment: I see the problem. The code is setting the current size from the box. So if you move fast in and out, the variables get the wrong values. You can fix this by storing the values before hand in attributes in the object, like I did in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$('div').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).attr('data-width', $(this).width());
        $(this).attr('data-height', $(this).height());
        $(this).stop().css({'zIndex':'5'}).animate({
            height : $(this).children().css('height'),
            width : $(this).children().css('width')
        }, speed);
        $(this).children().animate({
            left : '0',
            top : '0'
        }, speed);
    },
    function() {
        var w = $(this).attr('data-width');
        var h = $(this).attr('data-height')
        $(this).stop().css({'zIndex':'0'}).animate({
            height : h,
            width : w
        }, speed);
        $(this).children().animate({
            left : left[i],
            top : top[i]
        }, speed);
    }
);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/dVz6H/8/)